# Do I look OK in that shirt?

Tags: discussion

[image]

[Thanks for the welcome pack! First sun out in UK could not resist some DIY work.](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/uu6vrR-h6qFaGVJEnOD5cfAm4kVvKkOeJe1AyfFqKB0?feat=directlink)

:-)

Comment: What's the shirt say?  Sadly it would probably look better if you were a female member of the Swedish Bikini Team.

Comment: Oh, dear.  Sitting on the stoop, "Sanding my wood". I'm sure you didn't mean anything by that picture composition. ;)